# Passing a Selector or CodeBlock to UIButton events

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a `addButton` method that creates a button. I need the buttons `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to be attached to a CodeBlock.

Can you do that? I have also tried to pass in a `SEL(selector)`.

```
typedef void (^menuAction)();

- (void) addButton:(NSString*)title callback:(menuAction)action{
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(action)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a selector like this:

```
- (void) addButton:(NSString*)title withSelector:(SEL)selector {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    // set some frame
    CGRect f = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200);
    [button setFrame:f] ;

    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal] ;

    [button addTarget:self
               action:selector
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // add to view
    [self.view addSubview:button] ;

}
```

and use it like this:

```
-(void)doStuff {
    NSLog(@"doStuff");
}

[self addButton:@"some button" withSelector:@selector(doStuff)] ;
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for confirming this. I did tried this before, but this made me realise that I missed passing in the target as a parameter - to the instance actually containing the target method.